# Can't chown 0 (root) in Cygwin

Tags: root, cygwin, chown

This command:

```
rm -f testfile && touch testfile && chown 0 testfile
```

is failing in Cygwin with error:

> ```
> chown: changing ownership of 'testfile': Invalid argument
> ```

Why?

Comment: Because of ntfs filesystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot `chown` with `root` (0) account simply because there is no such thing in Cygwin.

Comment: OK. I think I'll just have to accept this. Literally and figuratively.

Comment: Captain obvious to the rescue ;)